# Convert three divs into display flex

Tags: html, css

I have this code

HTML:

```html
<div class="index-fifth">
  <div class="index-fifth-head">
    <h2>Why Us?</h2>
    <h1>Our Advantage</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="index-fifth-wrappers">
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper-1">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper-2">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper-3">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.index-fifth-head {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 50px;
        gap: 1em;
        color: #704a1b;
      }

      .index-fifth-head h1 {
        color: #614124;
      }

      .index-fifth-wrappers {
        font-size: 17px;
        background-color: #ffdc84;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 450px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #704a1b;
      }
```

Now, these divs are looking something like this (without using `display: flex` for the `.index-fifth-wrappers`):

[image]

Now, when I use `display: flex` and modify the code like this:

```css
.index-fifth-wrappers {
        font-size: 17px;
        background-color: #ffdc84;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 450px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #704a1b;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
```

This happens:

[image]

How can I make it look something like this?:

[image]

Comment: Please also show the styling for the divs inside the .index-fifth-wrappers

Comment: Isn't any styling for those. This is everything that I have.

Comment: Make the text smaller and add margin/padding to the containers of these cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the background color to each item and then set the wrapper width to `100%`. Adding a `gap` to the flex items and giving the items `flex: 1` will allow you to take out the `justify-content: space-between;`.

Take a look at this. I added a class `flex-item` to each item. Feel free to rename it.

```css
.index-fifth-head {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px;
  gap: 1em;
  color: #704a1b;
}

.index-fifth-head h1 {
  color: #614124;
}

.index-fifth-wrappers {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #704a1b;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: #ffdc84;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-fifth">
  <div class="index-fifth-head">
    <h2>Why Us?</h2>
    <h1>Our Advantage</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="index-fifth-wrappers">
    <div class="flex-item index-fifth-wrapper-1">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item index-fifth-wrapper-2">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item index-fifth-wrapper-3">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked the best for me personally, after some minor adjustments. Just modified it a little bit with the renaming and added a media query to change the flex-direction to column when the max-width hits 900px.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, it's just a case of moving some styling around in the different levels you've set up.

To ensure there is spacing between your `div`s inside `index-fifth-wrappers`, and because you're using `display: flex`, you can use `gap` to space the elements.
[MDN Docs for `gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

The next thing to do is to move the `background-color` and some `padding` to the inner `div`s (`index-fifth-wrapper-X`). I've added a shared class (`index-fifth-wrapper`) to target these.

EDIT:
You pointed out how there wouldn't be enough screen space, to which I would recommend wrapping he flex components with `media` queries.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Alternatively, you could make use of `overflow-x`, as others may have suggested

```css
.index-fifth-head {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  color: #704a1b;
}

.index-fifth-head h1 {
  color: #614124;
}

.index-fifth-wrappers {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #704a1b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
  .index-fifth-wrappers {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}


.index-fifth-wrapper {
  background-color: #ffdc84;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-fifth">
  <div class="index-fifth-head">
    <h2>Why Us?</h2>
    <h1>Our Advantage</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="index-fifth-wrappers">
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-1">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-2">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-3">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The width was too small for each individual flex item here. When readjusting it to increase the width, the items weren't aligned in the centre and a margin would have to be used to align them to the centre. Wouldn't be too handy when the screen width is adjusted

Comment: That's actually because of some of the unneeded styling on `.index-fifth-wrappers`, I'll remove it an update my answer. The other thing you need to consider is media breakpoints for when to change certain styling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the inner divs too.

(Note: Run in full screen for effect)

```css
.index-fifth-head {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px;
  gap: 1em;
  color: #704a1b;
}

.index-fifth-head h1 {
  color: #614124;
}

.index-fifth-wrappers {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #704a1b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.index-fifth-wrapper {
  background-color: #ffdc84;
  padding: 2vw;
  width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-fifth">
  <div class="index-fifth-head">
    <h2>Why Us?</h2>
    <h1>Our Advantage</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="index-fifth-wrappers">
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-1">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-2">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="index-fifth-wrapper index-fifth-wrapper-3">
      <div style="display: flex; gap: 1em; padding-top: 15px;">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital"></i>
        <p>Credible</p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 40px;">The medical consultants present on MedConnect are confirmed and cross-checked to be official and credible when they sign up on MedConnect. Through the relevant medical details that they <br> provide, MedConnect affirms them to be credible consultants.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This had a bit of x-overflow on full screen view.